# QNetworkAccessManager blocks its thread (freezes) when server unreachable

Tags: qt, ssl, qnetworkaccessmanager

When server is unreachable, `post()` from `QNetworkAccessManager(NAM)` blocks thread's `eventloop`, it practically freezes the thread, even if the timeout signal is triggered, the quit slot is not called, it is just appended to the queue (it is been debugged while using) and is called after NAM stops blocking it, which can be minute or two. SSL is checked and everything is correct, even the version of openssl library. If I use dynamically created NAM or timer, the behavior is the same. **Unknown error** is printed no slot is triggered from reply signals. No SSL error or the other.
The problem is that the thread is not responsive to user inputs either like quit the application which has to wait until the NAM stops blocking the eventloop. Quit slot of the thread of course tries to interrupt the `eventLoopServer` in the presented method, but the slot is called after the NAM stops blocking the thread's eventloop.

Any ideas how to set timer to NAM? Or to stay responsive? If I did not used local eventloop and just connect to finished signal, the behavior is the same (based on googling)

```
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), eventLoopServer, SLOT(quit()));
//eventLoopServer is created in init procedure, which is called after the thread of this controller class has been started
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), eventLoopServer, SLOT(quit()));

QNetworkRequest request( QUrl( QString("my url address") ) );//there is valid url (checked), not possible to share

QUrlQuery params;
params.addQueryItem("serial",licenseKey);
params.addQueryItem("pcid",pcid);
QByteArray postData ;
postData.append(params.toString());

QSslConfiguration conf = request.sslConfiguration();
conf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
request.setSslConfiguration(conf);

QNetworkReply *reply=mgr.post(request, postData);
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(processSSLError(QList<QSslError>)));
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(processError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),eventLoopServer, SLOT(quit()));

timer.start(5000);
eventLoopServer->exec();
QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();
qDebug()<<reply->errorString(); // prints "Unknown error"
```

Comment: I am using Windows 7-64bit  and Qt5.9Beta3 msvc2015 32bit

Comment: Please run this under a debug build of Qt and show exactly where it blocks in Qt code. This would be considered a bug.

Comment: I use debug, it stops at the eventLoopServer->exec() which is not quited using the timer if server is unreachable and quit(I put it in my own slot which calls quit of the eventloop while looking for bug in my code) is called immediately after the manager returns finish, which sometimes takes even 2 minutes. I am now thinking that it is a bug too, I just reported it to Qt.

Comment: `eventLoopServer->exec()` is not nearly enough information. Of course it will block "there", but `exec()` **itself** is **not** where it blocks. It will block somewhere further into Qt's insides, and you absolutely have to find out exactly **where** it's stuck to provide a useful error report!